# How to Project / Boolean curves on a Mesh with Geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm looking to use 2D curves that will then be projected onto my 3D mesh to add layered thickness/extrusions to my shoe like below:

[image]

I think I've worked out the best way to project the curves onto the mesh via a raycast node but when it comes to the boolean or mesh separation part I'm trying to use a mesh boolean node but I'm getting weird results?

Has anyone tried something similar or could recommend a better way for splitting apart the meshes to get 2 clean separate mesh islands?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this node setup:

[image]

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Note: The shoe isn't really connected to the extension, since i didn't know whether this is necessary or not. You can play a bit with the values to see what you can adapt.